# Create Failover Workgroup Cluster on EC2

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, failover

I would like to create a work group failover cluster (without domain controller) with Window Server 2016 in EC2. In my work group , I have a AG1 and AG2 server and both having a DNS suffix and i modify the HOSTS file. For example, AG1.sqlpassion.com and AG2.sqlpassion.com. Both server can ping each other without any problem.

Note that this is based on the steps in this website:
[How to create a SQL Server Availability Group without an Active Directory Domain](https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2016/01/11/how-to-create-a-sql-server-availability-group-without-an-active-directory-domain/)

Anyone can help me how to create a failover cluster?

My Attempts so far.

1. Use failover cluster manager to create MS Test cluster but fail with the following message

> An error occurred while creating the cluster.
>       An error occurred creating cluster 'MSTest'.
>       The RPC server is unavailable

2. PowerShell code to add cluster:

   `New-Cluster –Name MSTtest-Node AG1.sqlpassion.com,AG2.sqlpassion.com -AdministrativeAccessPoint DNS`

> The clustered role was not successfully created. For more information
>   view the report file below. Report file location:
>   C:\Windows\cluster\Reports\Create Cluster Wizard MSTest on 2017.12.22
>   At 11.13.24.htm New-Cluster : An error occurred while performing the
>   operation.
>       An error occurred while creating the cluster 'MSTest'.
>       An error occurred creating cluster 'MSTest'.
>       This operation returned because the timeout period expired

3. PowerShell code to add cluster:

   `New-Cluster –Name MSTest -Node AG1.sqlpassion.com,AG2.sqlpassion.com -StaticAddress 192.168.1.1 -AdministrativeAccessPoint DNS`

> New-Cluster : Static address '192.168.1.101' was not found on any
>   cluster network.
>       At line:1 char:1
>       + New-Cluster –Name MSTest -Node AG1.sqlpassion.com,AG2.sqlpassion.com  ...
>       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Cluster], ClusterCmdletException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSArgument,Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.NewClusterCommand

Answer (score 0):

There might be a firewall or security group rule preventing communication between the two servers.  For my testing I just created a new security group with all communication open from that same security group and assigned it to the two nodes only.